# Using Azure MSSQL "contained database" how do you force a user to reset their password?

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-user

I'm setting up new users in an Azure MSSQL Contained Database.

I want new users to be forced to reset their password on the first login.

I see the ability to set a new password documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 but I do not see the ability to force the reset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported and you cannot use Must_Chance, Check_Policy or Check_expiration as of now.

> Keyword or statement option 'check_policy' is not supported in this
>   version of SQL Server.

You can vote for this in the forum :

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/10491111-azure-sql-database-password-force-change-on-first

Comment: Thanks, that was my guess.